# Why doesn't String implement From<&String>?

Tags: rust, traits

**Background**

I know that in Rust people prefer `&str` rather than `&String`. But in some case we were only given `&String`.

One example is when you call `std::iter::Iterator::peekable`. The return value is a `Peekable<I>` object that wraps the original iterator into it and gives you one extra method `peek`.

The point here is that `peek` only gives you a reference to the iterator item. So if you have an iterator that contains `String`s, you only have `&String` in this case. Of cause, you can easily use `as_str` to get a `&str` but in the code I will show below it is equivalent to a call to `clone`.

**The question**

This code

```
#[derive(Debug)]
struct MyStruct(String);

impl MyStruct {
    fn new<T>(t: T) -> MyStruct
    where
        T: Into<String>,
    {
        MyStruct(t.into())
    }
}

fn main() {
    let s: String = "Hello world!".into();
    let st: MyStruct = MyStruct::new(&s);
    println!("{:?}", st);
}
```

doesn't compile because `String` doesn't implement `From<&String>`. This is not intuitive.

Why does this not work? Is it just a missing feature of the standard library or there are some other reasons that prevent the standard library from implementing it?

In the real code, I only have a reference to a `String` and I know to make it work I only need to call `clone` instead, but I want to know why.

Comment: I wouldn't say it is anti-intuitive - other objects don't do it either, e.g. `Vec<T>` doesn't `impl From<&Vec<T>>`; also `impl<'a> From<&'a str>` is much a more probable use case and it's readily available.

Comment: I feel that the real answer have something to do with my relevent question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45126120/if-intostring-not-implemented-for-string-why-these-implementations-are-co

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To solve your problem, one could imagine adding a new generic impl to the standard library:

```
impl<'a, T: Clone> From<&'a T> for T { ... }
```

Or to make it more generic:

```
impl<B, O> From<B> for O where B: ToOwned<Owned=O> { ... }
```

---

However, there are two problems with doing that:

1. **Specialization**: the specialization feature that allows to overlapping trait-impls is still unstable. It turns out that designing specialization in a sound way is way [more difficult than expected](https://aturon.github.io/blog/2017/07/08/lifetime-dispatch/) (mostly due to lifetimes).

   Without it being stable, the Rust devs are very careful not to expose that feature somewhere in the standard library's public API. This doesn't mean that it isn't used at all in std! A famous example is the specialized `ToString` impl for `str`. It was introduced [in this PR](https://github.com/rust-lang/rust/pull/32586). As you can read in the PR's discussion, they only accepted it because it does not change the API (`to_string()` was already implemented for `str`).

   However, it's different when we would add the generic impl above: it would change the API. Thus, it's not allowed in std yet.
2. **`core` vs `std`**: the traits `From` and `Into` are defined in the 
   [`core` library](https://doc.rust-lang.org/stable/core/), whereas `Clone` and `ToOwned` are defined in `std`. This means that we can't add a generic impl in `core`, because `core` doesn't know anything about `std`. But we also can't add the generic impl in `std`, because generic impls need to be in the same crate as the trait (it's a consequence of the orphan rules).

   Thus, it would required some form of refactoring and moving around definitions (which may or may not be difficult) before able to add such a generic impl.

---

Note that adding

```
impl<'a> From<&'a String> for String { ... }
```

... works just fine. It doesn't require specialization and doesn't have problems with orphan rules. But of course, we wouldn't want to add a specific impl, when the generic impl would make sense.

(*thanks to the lovely people on IRC for explaining stuff to me*)

Answer (score 1):

Since `String` does implement `From<&str>`, you can make a simple change:

```
fn main() {
    let s: String = "Hello world!".into();
    // Replace &s with s.as_str()
    let st: MyStruct = MyStruct::new(s.as_str());
    println!("{:?}", st);
}
```

All `&String`s can be trivially converted into `&str` via `as_str`, which is why all APIs should prefer to use `&str`; it's a strict superset of accepting `&String`.