# If `Into<String>` is not implemented for `&String`, why are these implementations conflicting?

Tags: rust, traits

I asked a [relevant question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45118060/why-doesnt-string-implement-fromstring) about why there is no implementation of `From<&String>` for `String`. I now want to create my own trait as the following:

```
#[derive(Debug)]
struct MyStruct(String);

impl MyStruct {
    fn new<T>(t: T) -> MyStruct
    where
        T: MyIntoString,
    {
        MyStruct(t.my_into())
    }
}

trait MyIntoString {
    fn my_into(self) -> String;
}

impl<'a> MyIntoString for &'a String {
    fn my_into(self) -> String {
        self.clone()
    }
}

impl<I> MyIntoString for I
where
    I: Into<String>,
{
    fn my_into(self) -> String {
        self.into()
    }
}

fn main() {
    let s: String = "Hello world!".into();
    let st: MyStruct = MyStruct::new(&s);
    println!("{:?}", st);
}
```

The compiler now claims that the two implementations of `MyIntoString` are conflicting. This is even weirder to me as we already see in the other question that `From<&String>` didn't implement for `String` and so it didn't find an implementation of `Into<String>` for `&String`. So how come this is conflicting now?

Furthermore, even when I turned on `#![feature(specialization)]`, the same conflict was detected.

**The error message**

According to one answer of this question, it looks like the error message didn't guide me to the right track.

So let me post the error message to blame, as it may changed in the future.

```
error[E0119]: conflicting implementations of trait `MyIntoString` for type `&std::string::String`:
  --> src/main.rs:23:1
   |
17 | / impl<'a> MyIntoString for &'a String {
18 | |     fn my_into(self) -> String {
19 | |         self.clone()
20 | |     }
21 | | }
   | |_- first implementation here
22 |   
23 | / impl<I> MyIntoString for I
24 | | where
25 | |     I: Into<String>,
26 | | {
...  |
29 | |     }
30 | | }
   | |_^ conflicting implementation for `&std::string::String`
```

To me, this is a claim by the compiler that there is a REAL conflict, not a potential one.

Comment: Related: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45033704/why-do-i-get-conflicting-implementations-of-trait-for-f32-which-does-not-imple

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The error is caused by the orphan rules (see The Book second ed. chapter 10.2 at the end of [Implementing a trait on a type](https://doc.rust-lang.org/book/second-edition/ch10-02-traits.html#implementing-a-trait-on-a-type)).

These prevents your code from breaking when there are minor changes (as per [RFC#1105](https://github.com/rust-lang/rfcs/blob/master/text/1105-api-evolution.md)) in crates you use. If the authors of the standard library decided to implement `Into<String>` for `&String`, then your program would contain a conflicting definition for `my_into` and would break. The addition of a trait implementation should be a minor change and shouldn't break your program.

[This post](https://internals.rust-lang.org/t/allow-to-go-around-e-g-the-orphan-rules-for-trait-implementations/4062/5) provides justification for the rule.

The Book suggests using the [newtype pattern](https://doc.rust-lang.org/book/second-edition/ch19-03-advanced-traits.html#the-newtype-pattern-to-implement-external-traits-on-external-types) to work around this issue.

```
#[derive(Debug)]
struct MyStruct(String);

impl MyStruct {
    fn new<T>(t: T) -> MyStruct
    where
        T: Into<String>,
    {
        MyStruct(t.into())
    }
}

struct Wrapper<'a>(&'a String);

impl<'a> From<Wrapper<'a>> for String  {
    fn from(t: Wrapper<'a>) -> String {
        t.0.clone()
    }
}

fn main() {
    let s: String = "Hello world!".into();
    let st: MyStruct = MyStruct::new(Wrapper(&s));
    println!("{:?}", st);
}
```

[Playground link](https://play.rust-lang.org/?gist=9da32e5f300a7bafa650fc10ece658ff&version=stable)

Comment: This code does the same thing as mine but in a completely different way. This code implements `Into<String>` on `Wrapper<'a> == &'a String`, but my code implements `MyIntoString` on `&'a String`. Both should be passed the orphan rule.

Comment: No. Blanket implementation of `MyIntoString` (that is `impl<I: Into<String>> MyIntoString for I`) combined with `impl MyIntoString for &String` creates potential for code breakage caused by minor changes in standard library. Newtype variant will not break.

Comment: I don't see how the orphan rule is relevant, since OP is implementing his own trait `MyIntoString`.

Comment: The orphan rules are made to allow for *negative reasoning* ("trait Y is not implemented for type X"), which is necessary from time to time. But OP's original problem is that the orphan rules are not strong enough in this case. We cannot apply negative reasoning to assume that `From<&String>` is not implemented for `String` (because such an impl can be added by a non-breaking change). But I guess you could explain this without mentioning "orphan rules" at all :/

Comment: @LukasKalbertodt, "orphan rule" is a relevant search term if one wants to explore the topic.

Comment: I think now I understand what the real problem is. The "conflict" is only potential, but the error message didn't even include this fact, and so I get confused when the "confilict" was proved that does not exist. So, it is the error message needed to blame.

Comment: And unfortunately, the solution or workaround in this answer is not better than calling `clone()` on the usage side. So it is not even a proper "workaround". But that is what we can get before specification stablised.

Comment: I adjusted this answer as the document of `Into` said we should not implement `Into` directly. Implement `From` instead.

Answer (score 0):

This code works with specialization

```
#![feature(specialization)]

#[derive(Debug)]
struct MyStruct(String);

impl MyStruct {
    fn new<T>(t: T) -> MyStruct
    where
        T: MyIntoString,
    {
        MyStruct(t.my_into())
    }
}

trait MyIntoString {
    fn my_into(self) -> String;
}

impl<'a> MyIntoString for &'a String {
    fn my_into(self) -> String {
        self.clone()
    }
}

default impl<I> MyIntoString for I 
{
    default fn my_into(self) -> String {
        String::from("FOO")
    }
}

fn main() {
    let s: String = "Hello world!".into();
    let st: MyStruct = MyStruct::new(&s);
    println!("{:?}", st);
}
```

So, AFAIU, your version can't be specialized since compiler can't decide which version is more `specialized`

## edit

Why code from previous question doesn't compile?
Because when you pass `&s` to `new` in

```
    let st: MyStruct = MyStruct::new(&s);
```

compiler consider `&s` as `&String`, and from code in `std` it see:

```
impl<T, U> Into<U> for T where U: From<T>

impl<T, U> Into<U> for T where U: From<T> {
    fn into(self) -> U {
        U::from(self)
    }
}

// From (and thus Into) is reflexive
#[stable(feature = "rust1", since = "1.0.0")]
impl<T> From<T> for T {
    fn from(t: T) -> T { t }
}
```

and since `From<&String>` is not implemented for `String` it show compile error. So you must explicitly say that `&s` is type from which `String` can be constructed, that is `&str`

```
    let st: MyStruct = MyStruct::new(&s as &str);
```

and now compiler can see this

```
impl<'a> From<&'a str> for String
```

> The compiler now claim that the two implementation of MyIntoString are > conflicting. This is even weirder to me as we already see in the other > question that From<&String> didn't implement for String and so it
>   didn't find an implementation of Into for &String

The error happen just because compiler cannot decide which implementation is more `specialized` even if you use specialization.

Comment: The main point of this question is not about specialization. It is about why `&'a String` is considered as implemented `Into<String>` in this context but not in another.

Comment: because of automatic dereferencing

Comment: Please explain in your answer, along with your workaround.

Comment: `&String` can be considered as one which implement `Into<String>` when you try call `into` on its instance because of `automatic dereferencing`. But, in my code `&String` considered as `MyIntoString` because of I implemented this trait for `&String`.
In your code it doesn't work because misusing of `specialization`.

Comment: If you read my other question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45118060/why-doesnt-string-implement-fromstring, you know I am actually not able to call `into` on a `&String`. So I didn't understand why it is automatic dereferenced here but not there.

Comment: Code from your previous question doesn't compiles since compiler dereferenced `&s`  in type you didn't expected. To fix that you need to write `let st: MyStruct = MyStruct::new(&s as &str);`

Comment: I didn't understand. Yes your "fix" works, but only when I introduce a new type `&str` rather than `&String`. But I was expected an implementation for `&String`, not `&str`. So, if no implementation found for `&String` why it implements `Into<String>`?

Comment: `So, if no implementation found for &String why it implements Into<String>` -- it doesn't. It's not implemented in `std`. Why? I think because you can convert &String into String with dereferencing, that most natural way to do it.

Comment: Putting things together, it is weird isn't it: the compiler think you are able to call `into` on an `&String` so it don't let you implementing "conflicting" implementations. But as soon as you try to call `into` on `&String` the compiler said you cannot because you didn't implement for this.