# Implementing TryFrom shall I use &str or String

Tags: rust

I have a type `Instruction` and would use `std::convert::TryFrom` to convert from a string.

Shall I implement over `String` or `&str`? If I use `&str` I am obliged to
use `&*` pattern or `as_ref()`.

I have something like: [Rust Playground permalink](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=nightly&mode=release&edition=2018&gist=ce3b7f6c83b8f72cc8c08d573d2ed69c)

```rust
use std::convert::TryFrom;
enum Instruction {
    Forward, /* other removed for brievity */
}
#[derive(Debug)]
struct InstructionParseError(char);
impl std::convert::TryFrom<&str> for Instruction {
    type Error = InstructionParseError;    
    fn try_from(input: &str) -> Result<Self, Self::Error> {
      match input {
        "F" => Ok(Instruction::Forward),
        _ => unimplemented!(), // For brievity
      }
    }
}

fn main() {
    // I use a string because this input can come from stdio.
    let instr = String::from("F");
    let instr = Instruction::try_from(&*instr);
}
```

I read this answer: [Should Rust implementations of From/TryFrom target references or values?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48244892/should-rust-implementations-of-from-tryfrom-target-references-or-values) but i am wondering what is the best option: Implement both? Use `impl` avanced typing?

Comment: I think you should only implement it for `&str` but you could add an impl for `&String` but that not really important your type can be construct from &str, any struct other than String could have a str representation and you can't impl TryFrom for every type, let the user do the transformation to str should be ok

Comment: Yes but I will force user to use `&*val` or `val.as_ref()` if this user pass a `val: String`, alas the compiler message is terrible... Would avoid a bad developer experience in this case, if there is an idiomatic way it would be perfect.

Answer (score 2):

One solution I think after reading @SirDarius' comment is just to implement also for `String`
and use `as_ref()` or `&*` inside.

```rust
use std::convert::TryFrom;
enum Instruction {
    Forward, /* other removed for brievity */
}
#[derive(Debug)]
struct InstructionParseError(char);
impl std::convert::TryFrom<String> for Instruction {
    type Error = InstructionParseError;    
    fn try_from(input: String) -> Result<Self, Self::Error> {
        Instruction::try_from(input.as_ref())
    }
}
```

Like described here [Should Rust implementations of From/TryFrom target references or values?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48244892/should-rust-implementations-of-from-tryfrom-target-references-or-values) maybe in the future if some change is made with blanket implemation, `AsRef` will be usable.

Comment: @SirDarius: Oh thanks for your correction! I assumed the usage was like on github/gitlab etc. Didn't saw the @ transformed into a link so I edited :)

Answer (score -2):

*** This doesn't actually work as SirDarius points out below.

Use `T: AsRef<str>`.

```
impl<T: AsRef<str>> std::convert::TryFrom<T> for Instruction {
    type Error = InstructionParseError;    
    fn try_from(input: T) -> Result<Self, Self::Error> {
      let input: &str = input.as_ref();
      match input {
        "F" => Ok(Instruction::Forward),
        _ => unimplemented!(), // For brievity
     }
    }
}
```

Comment: This would be a pretty idiomatic solution, except that it conflicts with the blanket implementation from `core` for TryFrom: `impl<T, U> TryFrom<U> for T where U: Into<T>;`and therefore does not compile.

Comment: Dang it, I always run into that.

Comment: It's forbidden due to orphan rule ? Just read this [issue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45126120/if-intostring-is-not-implemented-for-string-why-are-these-implementation?rq=1) and read again [ch10-02 trait](https://doc.rust-lang.org/book/ch10-02-traits.html).